# Getting StackOverFlow error while trying to code Merge Sort in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I am new to coding and I was trying to create merge sort algorithm in java. I am getting too many errors and I am not able to figure out the exact mistake
in the code.
I feel my logic is correct but don't know which step(s) is causing the error. Could someone help me rectify the mistakes in the following code.
Thank you

```
package com.company;
public class MergeSort_Array {
    //Method created to print Input Array
    public static void printInputArray(int inputArray[]) {
        for (int i:inputArray) { //for-each loop
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    //Function created to sort and merge Input Array:
    public static void SortArray(int[] A) {
        int midpoint = A.length / 2;
        int[] left = new int[midpoint];
        int[] right;
        if (A.length % 2 == 0) {
            right = new int[midpoint];
        } else {
            right = new int[midpoint + 1];
        }
        //Copying values from super Array to left Array:
        for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++) {
            left[i] = A[i];
        }
        //Copying elements from super Array to right Array:
        for (int j = 0; j < right.length; j++) {
            right[j] = A[midpoint + j];
        }
        //using Recursion
        SortArray(left);
        SortArray(right);
        MergeArray(A, left, right);
    }

    // Creating a Function to merge left and right arrays.
    public static void MergeArray(int[] result, int[] L, int[] R) {
        //result array length = length of left array+ right array length
        result = new int[L.length + R.length];
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        while (k < result.length) {
            if (L[i] < R[j]) {
                result[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            } else
            if (R[j] < L[i]) {
                result[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            } else
            if (i > L.length) {
                while (j <= R.length) {
                    result[k] = R[j];
                    j++;
                }
            } else
            if (j > R.length && i <= L.length) {
                while (i <= L.length) {
                    result[k] = L[i];
                    i++;
                }
            }
            k++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inputArray = { 2, 5, 4, 1, 7, 9, 6 };
        MergeSort_Array ms = new MergeSort_Array();
        ms.printInputArray(inputArray);
        SortArray(inputArray);

        for (int i: inputArray) {
            System.out.println(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from your primary problem (which I've explained in the answer) you also overwrite `result` with a new `int[]` when you should really just write the result to the array passed in (i.e. get rid of the line `result = new int[L.length + R.length];`).

Comment: @ShantanuStudyCircle: You can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

**Every** time you call `SortArray` it will itself call `SortArray` twice. There is no end condition: **every** invocation will try to call `SortArray` twice.

This means that no call of `SortArray` can ever complete, since you infinitely recurse in each of them.

There must be some base case where it no longer calls itself. For mergesort one *usually* switches to some other algorithm once the array is small enough, but for simplicities sake you can even fall back to the most trivial base case for sorting: any array shorter than 2 elements is always sorted and needs nothing else to be done to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- **[Major]** `SortArray()` always attempts to split the array and sort both halves. You should not do this if the array length is less than 2, otherwise you get an infinite recursion causing a **stack overflow** exception.
- **[Hint]** `right` can be initialized unconditionally as `int[] right = new int[A.length - midpoint];`
- **[Major]** `MergeArray` should not reallocate the destination array. The merge must be performed in place into `result` so the caller's object is updated.
- **[Major]** in the merge loop, you must test the index values **before** attempting to read `L[i]` or `R[j]`, otherwise you might get an out of bounds exception.

Here is a modified version:

```
package com.company;
public class MergeSort_Array {
    // Method created to print Input Array
    public static void printInputArray(int inputArray[]) {
        for (int i : inputArray) { //for-each loop
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    //Function created to sort and merge Input Array:
    public static void SortArray(int[] A) {
        if (A.length >= 2) {
            int midpoint = A.length / 2;
            int[] left = new int[midpoint];
            int[] right = new int[A.length - midpoint];

            //Copying values from super Array to left Array:
            for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++) {
                left[i] = A[i];
            }
            //Copying elements from super Array to right Array:
            for (int j = 0; j < right.length; j++) {
                right[j] = A[midpoint + j];
            }
            //using Recursion
            SortArray(left);
            SortArray(right);
            MergeArray(A, left, right);
        }
    }

    // Creating a Function to merge left and right arrays.
    public static void MergeArray(int[] result, int[] L, int[] R) {
        for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; k < result.length; k++) {
            if (j >= R.length || (i < L.length && L[i] < R[j])) {
                result[k] = L[i++];
            } else {
                result[k] = R[j++];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inputArray = { 2, 5, 4, 1, 7, 9, 6 };
        printInputArray(inputArray);
        SortArray(inputArray);
        printInputArray(inputArray);
    }
}
```